# Modificar el valor de una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy queriendo hacer un juego de Piedra, Papel o Tijera en Python, nada complicado. El jugador empieza con 2 puntos y dependiendo si gana o pierda se suma o se resta valor. El problema es que no se guarda en la variable que yo declaro primero, de modo que aunque llegue a 0 puntos el while se sigue ejecutando.

```
from random import randint

pi = "Piedra"
pa = "Papel"
ti = "Tijera"

puntos = 2

while puntos > 0:


    elemento = input("¿Piedra, papel o tijera? : ")
    maquina = randint(0,2)


    def piedra(puntos):
        if elemento.lower() == "piedra" and maquina == 0:
            print ("Empate, la maquina eligio ", pi , " ! ")
        elif elemento.lower() == "piedra" and maquina == 1:
            print ("Perdiste, la maquina eligio ", pa, " ! ")
            puntos -= 2
            print ("Tienes " , puntos , " puntos.")
        elif elemento.lower() == "piedra" and maquina == 2:
            print ("Ganaste, la maquina eligio ", ti, " ! ")
            puntos += 2
            print ("Tienes " , puntos , " puntos.")

    def papel(puntos):
        if elemento.lower() == "papel" and maquina == 0:
            print ("Ganaste, la maquina eligio ", pi, " ! ")
            print ("Tienes " , puntos , " puntos.")
            puntos += 2
        elif elemento.lower() == "papel" and maquina == 1:
            print ("Empate, la maquina eligio ", pa, " ! ")
        elif elemento.lower() == "papel" and maquina == 2:
            print ("Perdiste, , la maquina eligio " , ti, " ! ")
            puntos -= 2
            print ("Tienes " , puntos , " puntos.")

    def tijera(puntos):
        if elemento.lower() == "tijera" and maquina == 0:
            print ("Perdiste, la maquina eligio " , pi, " ! ")
            puntos -= 2
            print ("Tienes " , puntos , " puntos.")
        elif elemento.lower() == "tijera" and maquina == 1:
            print ("Ganaste, la maquina eligio " , pa, " ! ")
            print ("Tienes " , puntos , " puntos.")
            puntos += 2
        elif elemento.lower() == "tijera" and maquina == 2:
            print ("Empate, la maquina eligio " , ti, " ! ")

    piedra(puntos)
    papel(puntos)
    tijera(puntos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable que recibe cada función, es una copia del valor, con lo cuál no estás modificando la variable fuera del scope local. Si queres modificar la de afuera, capaz te conviene no pasarla "puntos" como parametro, y deberías usar al principio de cada funcion:

```
def piedra():
    global puntos  # A partir de aquí, podes acceder a la variable que declaraste al inicio del módulo. El codigo sigue igual como lo tenes.
```

Fijate si te sirve :)

Comment: En caso de no pasarla como parametro, que me recomendarías para tener un sistema de puntos que empiece con X y vaya aumentando o restándose según pierda/gane ?

Comment: Ahí modifiqué la respuesta. La idea es que, usando "global puntos", accedas siempre a la misma variable que declaraste arriba. Creo que con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Bien, pero al parecer si yo tengo 2 puntos, sale un empate y luego gano o pierdo sigue en 2 puntos, quizas incluso en empate deba poner un puntos += 0 ? Esta vez no paso ningun parametro "puntos" simplemente hago todo tal cual me dijiste arriba. Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Ya lo resolvi! Tengo el print antes de la suma, que papanata soy!

Comment: Buenisimo! En general, usar variables globales, no es buena práctica. Pero bueno...para este caso sirve jeje. La otra es usar un esquema de clases, pero bueno, ya es otra cuestión.

Comment: Bien, no se me ocurren muchas otras formas de hacerlo. Buscando en internet no suelen usar funciones piedra(),papel(),tijera(). Directamente hacen "if's" . Pero bueno, queria buscar algo mas rebuscado y personalizado. Saludos y gracias nuevamente!